# Test-Path : Illegal characters in path

Tags: powershell

I am trying to download a video series from channel9 using powershell, however I get this error on the first file, I think its the pipe character, but even with the replace statement its not working

```
 function Get-Media
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Object]
        $url,
        [Object]
        $title,
        [Object]
        $path
    )

    $u = New-Object System.Uri($url)
    $name = $title
    $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($u.Segments[-1])
    $fileName = $name + $extension

    $fileName = $fileName -replace "â€™", ''
    $fileName = $fileName -replace "\?", ''
    $fileName = $fileName -replace ":", ''
    $fileName = $fileName -replace '/', ''
    $fileName = $fileName -replace ",", ''
    $fileName = $fileName -replace '"', ''
    $fileName = $fileName -replace '|', ''
    $fileName = $fileName -replace '\#', ''
    $fileName = $fileName -replace '-', ''

    $fileName

    if (Test-Path($fileName)) {
        Write-Host 'Skipping file, already downloaded' -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    else
    {
        Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile (Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath $fileName)
    }
}

function Get-VideosFromFeed
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Object]
        $feedUrl,
        [Object]
        $folder,
        [Object]
        $path
    )

    $feed=[xml](New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString($feedUrl)

    $downloadPath = (Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath $folder)

    if (Test-Path($downloadPath)) {
        Write-Host 'Skipping folder, already exists' -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    else
    {
        New-Item -Path $downloadPath -ItemType directory -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
    }

    foreach($i in $feed.rss.channel.item) {
        foreach($m in $i.group){
            foreach($u in $m.content `
                    | Where-Object { `
                            $_.url -like '*mid.mp4' `
                         } | Select-Object -Property @{Name='url'; Expression = {$_.url}}, `
                                                     @{Name='title'; Expression = {$i.title}})
            {
                Get-Media -url $u.url -title $u.title -path $downloadPath
            }
        }
    }
}

$physicalPath = "D:\Videos\Series"

Get-VideosFromFeed -feedUrl 'https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/azurestack/feed/mp4high'                                                                          -path $physicalPath -folder 'azurestack'
```

Comment: It's not clear to me where the error occurs. Please show the exact error message in your question.

Comment: Error is downloading the first video, copy paste the entire code and you should reproduce it

Comment: @EstebanV Have you tried my suggestion below?

Comment: you have to scroll to the right side to see the entire script, the error occurs when download the first video from the RSS Feed: Get-VideosFromFeed -feedUrl 'https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/azurestack/feed/mp4high'                                                                          -path $physicalPath -folder 'azurestack'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe, you should replace this strange piece of code:

```
$fileName = $fileName -replace "â€™", ''
$fileName = $fileName -replace "\?", ''
$fileName = $fileName -replace ":", ''
$fileName = $fileName -replace '/', ''
$fileName = $fileName -replace ",", ''
$fileName = $fileName -replace '"', ''
$fileName = $fileName -replace '|', ''
$fileName = $fileName -replace '\#', ''
$fileName = $fileName -replace '-', ''
```

With this:

```
$fileName = $fileName -replace '(-|#|\||"|,|/|:|â|€|™|\?)', ''
```

I work behind a strict proxy and can't test the entire process, but at least I don't get the 'Illegal characters in path' error.

Btw you don't need to replace all of the stuff. Only theese characters: `<>:"/\|?*` according to [naming rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So the better regex pattern should be like this: `-replace '\<|\>|:|"|/|\\|\||\?|\*', ''`

Comment: will test later tonight and let you know!.

Answer (score 5):

You could also try this:

```
$FileName.Split([IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()) -join ''
```

It seems quite effective to me :)

Comment: I prefer this answer over n01d's answer. This way you put the responsibility of the list of char's at the OS. And it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like are calling Get-VideosFromFeed without the $Folder or $Path parameters.

You might need to set some default values or hand them in when calling the function.

Try calling it like this:

```
Get-VideosFromFeed -feedUrl 'https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/azurestack/feed/mp4high' -folder "Folder" -Path "C:\Path"
```

Comment: It looks like I didnt paste the entire line, the parameters are there, did you try to run the entire script? Can you show me that it worked for you, for me with the first video I get the error above

Comment: I checked, the code is ok, but you have to scroll to the right, please copy and paste everything and it will also fail for you, the error occurs when downloading the first video from the rss feed. Get-VideosFromFeed -feedUrl 'https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/azurestack/feed/mp4high'                                                                          -path $physicalPath -folder 'azurestack'

Answer (score 1):

This line doesn't do anything:

```
$fileName = $fileName -replace '|', ''
```

The first argument to -replace is a regex. It's finding every empty string in $fileName and replacing it with the empty string. Aside from wasting a bunch of CPU cycles, this has no effect.

You need to escape the pipe character inside the regex.

```
$fileName = $fileName -replace '\|', ''
```